# Cannot compute least sort of term (where the terms are lists)

Tags: kframework

I have the following productions:

```
syntax Id
syntax Exp ::= Id
syntax Exps ::= List{Exp, ","}
syntax Ids ::= List{Id, ","}
```

What does this error mean?

```
[Error] Critical: Cannot compute least sort of term:
_,__KOOL-UNTYPED-SYNTAX(Id(#"x"),, .List{"_,__KOOL-UNTYPED-SYNTAX"}(.KList)).
Possible sorts are [Ids, Exps], but their least common subsort is
GeneratedListBottom{_,__KOOL-UNTYPED-SYNTAX}, which is not a possible sort.All
terms must have a unique least sort; consider assigning unique KLabels to
overloaded productions/completing the subsort lattice.
  while evaluating function project:Stmts
  while evaluating function initKCell
  while evaluating function initThreadCell
  while evaluating function initThreadsCell
  while evaluating function initTCell
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

K is not sure whether the term `x, .List` is an `Ids` or an `Exps`.

We want to tell K that:

1. All Lists of Ids are Lists of Exps:

   ```
   syntax Exps ::= Ids
   ```
2. Lists of Ids with the same elements as a list of Exps are the same.
   We tell K that `Exps` and `Ids` parse to the same AST node using the `klabel` attribute:

   ```
   syntax Exps ::= List{Exp, ","} [klabel(exps)]
   syntax Ids ::= List{Id, ","} [klabel(exps)]
   ```